# Android, LinearLayout won't scroll

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I am relatively new to android programing. Can anybody tell me why my `ScrollView` won't scroll?

My activity has implemented `OnGestureListener` for getting some touch information. But, I tried to disable `onGestureListener` and it still won't work.

It works outside of the SlidingDrawer. Is it possible to get it work inside of the SlidingDrawer?

I solved it by giving to ScrollView ID and then put that ID in SlidingDrawer android:content="@+id/content".

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@drawable/pozadina_touchpad"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <SlidingDrawer
                android:id="@+id/prosirenje"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:content="@+id/content"
                android:handle="@+id/handle" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/handle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/gumb_slider"
                     />

                <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/content"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/slider"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:onClick="nemaSkrola"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/ico_povecalo"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="20dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/ikona_povecalo" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/ico_desktop"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="20dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/ikona_komp" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/ico_daljinski"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="20dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/ikona_play" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/ico_tipkovnica"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="20dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/ikona_tipka" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/ico_settings"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="20dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/ikona_settings" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </ScrollView>

            </SlidingDrawer>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try to remove the android:onClick="nemaSkrola" just to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: try putting in your parent LinearLayout 
android:fillViewport="true"
android:scrollbars="vertical" and in ScrollView  android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

Comment: thanks guys but still nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give some value to scrollView's width and height and try like this

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@id/content"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

please change scrollview id like this:

```
android:id="@id/content"
```

please change handle button id like this:

```
android:id="@id/handle"
```

Answer (score 1):

The containers (hierarchical parents) of the `ScrollView` have the following attribute set this way: `android:layout_height="match_parent"`, which forces them to limit their content to the height of the activity (screen). 
For your `ScrollView` to work, try to get the `ScrollView` to a higher hierarchical level, so that won't be constrained by its parent.

Comment: that works... but if I put the ScrollView in SlidingDrawer it wont work... is it posible to get it work in SlidingDrawer?